# Android Metadata Lookup Service

Tags: android, metadata, lookup

iTunes provides a [Lookup Service](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=481664999) for gathering metadata as JSON of an app given an app ID.

Is there a similar service for Android? It needn't be a web service or necessarily return JSON, a Java API or similar would also be useful.

Since Android has many stores, there may be many lookup services. If so, as many APIs as needed would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no tool that exists for Android at the minute.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this one can help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what I'm after. I'm not looking for a search feature, but a lookup feature, where I can garner the information I want from the lookup and then present selected information to the user.